# Debezium postgres kafka connector is failing with java heap space issue

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, strimzi

we have 13 kafka debezium postgres connectors running on Strimzi kafkaconnect cluster. One of them is failing with `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` . Increased jvm options from 2g to 4g, but still its failing with the same issue.

complete log:

````
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:207)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.TextBuffer.setCurrentAndReturn(TextBuffer.java:696)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._finishAndReturnString(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2405)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.getValueAsString(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:312)
    at io.debezium.document.JacksonReader.parseArray(JacksonReader.java:219)
    at io.debezium.document.JacksonReader.parseDocument(JacksonReader.java:131)
    at io.debezium.document.JacksonReader.parseArray(JacksonReader.java:213)
    at io.debezium.document.JacksonReader.parseDocument(JacksonReader.java:131)
    at io.debezium.document.JacksonReader.parse(JacksonReader.java:102)
    at io.debezium.document.JacksonReader.read(JacksonReader.java:72)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.wal2json.NonStreamingWal2JsonMessageDecoder.processMessage(NonStreamingWal2JsonMessageDecoder.java:54)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection$1.deserializeMessages(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:418)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection$1.readPending(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:412)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.java:119)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:99)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator$$Lambda$464/1759003957.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)```
````

Comment: How many columns do you capture across all white-listed tables?

Comment: @Gunnar around 100k records per day for each connector

Comment: I didn't mean frequency of changes, but how many columns are you capturing altogether. The connector needs to keep metadata per column, so if you got many (like hundreds of thousands), you might need more memory.

Comment: @Gunnar its reading 6 columns

Comment: Ok, that's not it then. Are you working with large records and/or long transactions, though? Worth trying `wal2json_streaming` as `plugin.name`, or better yet `pgoutput` or `decoderbufs` (depending on your environment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you have a very large transaction message coming and the parsing fails due to memory constraints. `wal2json_streaming` should split the message into smaller chunks preventing this problem.

Genreally if possible please use either protobuf or pgoutput decoders as they are streaming messages from database per change not per transaction.

Comment: after changing to wal2json_streaming connector is working fine, but I see below Warning.
`WARN Received 10001 events which were all filtered out, so no offset could be committed. This prevents the replication slot from acknowledging the processed WAL offsets, causing a growing backlog of non-removeable WAL segments on the database server. Consider to either adjust your filter configuration or enable heartbeat events (via the heartbeat.interval.ms option) to avoid this situation. (io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource)`

Comment: This is documented in https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.1/connectors/postgresql.html#wal-disk-space

Answer (score 1):

Try tuning below Debezium props

- Increase `max.batch.size`
- Decrease `max.queue.size`
- Tune your `offset.flush.interval.ms` as your application requirement

Comment: I increased them from defaults to ```max.queue.size: 65536
    max.batch.size: 16384```. But still seeing the same issue